# My Jquery/Javascript will not connect! - works in HTML - NEW to programming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I can not figure out why my jquery/javascript won't show up on my loaded web page.
When I put it in the actual HTML file it works.

Everytime I try to link the js, jquery file it fails. I don't understand. Please help!!

NMC

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

window.onload=function(){
$('#one').hide();
$('#two').hide();
$('#three').hide();

});

$(function() {
 
  $("#menu-circle").on("mouseenter", function() {
 var i = $(this).index();
 $("#one").eq(i)
   .show().siblings().hide();
  });
  
$("#menu-circle1").on("mouseenter", function() {
 var i = $(this).index();
 $("#two").eq(i)
   .show().siblings().hide();
  });

$("#menu-circle3").on("mouseenter", function() {
 var i = $(this).index();
 $("#three").eq(i)
   .show().siblings().hide();
  }); 
 
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 9999 }, 'slow');
 });
}

 });
}

 });
}
```

```css
#one {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 100px;
 height: 50%;
 width: 80%;
 margin-top: 20%;
 position: fixed;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-top: 10%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: 50%;
 justify-content: left;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.62);
 z-index: 1;
 background-color:rgba(109, 104, 104, 0.54)
}

#two {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 100px;
 height: 50%;
 width: 80%;
 margin-top: 20%;
 position: fixed;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-top: 10%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: 50%;
 justify-content: left;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.62);
 z-index: 1;
 background-color:rgba(109, 104, 104, 0.54)
}
 
#three {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 100px;
 height: 50%;
 width: 80%;
 margin-top: 20%;
 position: fixed;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 padding-top: 10%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: 50%;
 justify-content: left;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.62);
 z-index: 1;
 background-color:rgba(109, 104, 104, 0.54)
}

.wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 2500px;
 margin-top: -30px;
 background-image: url("joaquinmiller.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center center;
 background-size: cover;
 filter: grayscale (100%);
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
 filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.wrapper:hover {
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); 
   filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.menunav {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 90%;
  margin-top: 40%;
}

#menu-circle {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: gray;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu-text {
 text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-weight:700;
 letter-spacing: .07em;
 opacity: 1;   
}

.menu-item:hover #menu-circle{
    background:yellow;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu-item:hover .menu-text{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: yellow;
    opacity: 1.0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-circle1 {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: gray;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu-text1 {
 text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-weight:700;
 letter-spacing: .07em;
 opacity: 1;   
}

.menu-item1:hover #menu-circle1 {
    background:yellow;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu-item1:hover .menu-text1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: yellow;
    opacity: 1.0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu-circle3 {
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background: gray;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 20px;
 opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu-text1 {
 text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
 font-weight:700;
 letter-spacing: .07em;
 opacity: 1;   
}

.menu-item3:hover #menu-circle3 {
    background:yellow;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.menu-item1:hover .menu-text1 {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: yellow;
    opacity: 1.0;
    text-decoration: none;
}


.topcontainer {
 position: !important;
 width: 100%;
 filter: grayscale(100%)
}

.topcontainer:hover {
 filter: grayscale(0%)
}

button {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 border-style: none;
 color: white;
 font-size: 15px;
}

button p {
 font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
<title>FINAL</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="evenmorepractice.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<header>

</header>

<div class="menunav">
  <div class="menu-item">
   <div id="menu-circle"></div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="menu-item1">
   <div id="menu-circle1"></div>
       </div>
    
  <div class="menu-item3">
   <div id="menu-circle3"></div>
       </div>
 </div>
     
    <article>
      <p id="one">Neighborhoods<button><p>click</p></button></p>
   <p id="two">History<button>click</button></p>
   <p id="three">Housing Crisis<button>readmore</button></p>
 </article>


<div class"whitenav">whitenav</div>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <p class="oakland">OAKLAND</p>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference your script in the head of the html file.  So right below the  tag where you add jquery, you need to add this:

```
<script src="path\to\your\js\file"></script>
```

Comment: I added <script src="main.js"></script> to my head, it was at the bottom right before the closed body tag. but nothing! - THANK YOU for your reply!

Comment: and main.js is in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: This is incorrect, your script tag does not have to be in the header. Where you had it is perfectly fine.

Comment: oh, i didn't even see that at the bottom, you're right

Answer (score 0):

Your JS file is really messed up, i think this is what you're looking for..

```
            $(function() {

                $('#one').hide();
                $('#two').hide();
                $('#three').hide();

                $("#menu-circle").on("mouseenter", function() {
                    var i = $(this).index();
                    $("#one").eq(i)
                    .show().siblings().hide();
                });

                $("#menu-circle1").on("mouseenter", function() {
                    var i = $(this).index();
                    $("#two").eq(i)
                    .show().siblings().hide();
                });

                $("#menu-circle3").on("mouseenter", function() {
                    var i = $(this).index();
                    $("#three").eq(i)
                    .show().siblings().hide();
                }); 

                $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 9999 }, 'slow');

            });
```

Comment: thank you for responding, replaced my JS with what you suggested but still nothing!

Comment: I copied the code over to jsbin and it seems to be running fine.
http://jsbin.com/jekigitegi/edit

Comment: Thank you for your help, i so appreciate it! I think I may have figured it out. Does your JS have to be saved to an index.html file? It finally worked after I moved it over. (created a new folder, copy pasted all files, and gave the .html a new name, index.html - before it was evenmorepractice.html

Comment: No it works in its own js file. I see in your example you have a script tag for <script src="script.js"></script> but in your comment on Austins answer you said you added <script src="main.js"></script> to your header. What is the name of the file you are storing the javascript in?

Comment: Here is a plunkr example that will show you it working in different files
https://plnkr.co/edit/9oB1JKyyFc7BRCWPS0d7?p=preview

Comment: i removed from the header and added back to below the body but this is what is confusing. i tried it here: http://www.lewinedesign.com/wnm601/final/new/evenmorepractice.html - doesn't work - and here: http://www.lewinedesign.com/wnm601/javatest/ - does work!

Comment: If you look in your browser console you would see that the first one isnt working because it cant find your main.js file.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://www.lewinedesign.com/wnm601/final/new/main.js